# Infinite bouncing of ball (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently creating a simple game like the `Angry Bird`. So I succesfully created something like that and I'm currently facing a problem where in I want to shoot the bird infinitely like if it hits the wall it should just bounce back and if it hits a wall again it will bounce back like infinite.

Here's my shoot code

```
public float force = 1300;

private void OnMouseUp()
{
    // Disable IsKenematic
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic = false;

    // Add the Force
    Vector2 dir = startPos - (Vector2)transform.position;
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(dir * force);


    //Remove the script (not the gameobject)
    Destroy(this);

}
```

## EDIT

Just to add an information I am using Physics 2D material
Friction: 0.8
Bounciness: 0.45

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yehey thanks for the help guys finally able to control the ball by doing this setting on the rigidbody and physics 2d material

rigidbody
drag all off
gravity is zero

physics 2d material
friction is 0
bounciness is 1

THANK YOU

Answer (score 3):

Set the Rigidbody.Drag of the game object to 0.

More info on what Drag does: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-drag.html

You should set the Rigidbody.GravityScale too to 0.

If you want to control the constant speed too change Rigidbody.Velocity.Magnitude.

Comment: nope this won't solve my problem . I want my object(ball) be like the breakout game which is continues to bounce every time it hits something\

Comment: Then you must also set the gravityScale to 0 - Answer edited

Comment: Almost near I only need to adjust the constant speed

Comment: Rigidbody.Velocity.Magnitude is what you should tune then - Added to answer

Comment: I used it for my 2D game, Magnitude is the magnitude of the velocity vector your gameobject has, you should tune this if you want to add or reduce the velocity of your object. To increase it try rb.velocity.magnitude += amountToIncrease;

Comment: Also I noticed you set the isKinematic to false. In reality if you want to do a game like breakout you should set isKinematic to true. Kinematic means that it can move but it is not affected by the physics of the game, like you want.

Comment: Don't worry because I'm setting it to isKinematic because I need to swing first the ball before it goes to play

Answer (score 0):

Originally answered [HERE](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1291263/how-can-i-cause-a-sphere-to-bounce-infinitely-with.html) , you could use the suggested ZeroFriction material for walls, etc. I've used this in one previous attempt and it worked fine.